# Simple autoencoder in theano optimizing using Scipy Optimize minimum

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, theano, minimize

Hi I am trying to build a simple autoencoder model in Theano but I also want to optimize using Scipy Optimize Minimize. I found a code here : http://dlacombejr.github.io/programming/2015/09/13/sparse-filtering-implemenation-in-theano.html which I modified a bit. The problem is since scipy minimum takes in an array, but I need to optimize more that one weight parameters. what is the solution to this problem if I want to keep using the same structure as the code in the link?

I found a possible way of getting around this problem, that is to pass in all the weights as a single array flattened and appended, and then assigning parts of the array to various variables, according to this https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3131

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as t
import numpy as np

class SparseFilter(object):

    def __init__(self, theta, dims, x):
        # assign inputs to sparse filter
        self.theta = theta
        self.x = x
        self.dims = dims

        self.w = theano.shared(np.random.randn(self.dims[1], self.dims[0]), name='w')
        self.w = t.reshape(self.theta[0:(self.dims[0]*self.dims[1])], self.dims)

        self.b = theano.shared(np.random.randn(self.dims[1]), name='b')
        self.b = t.reshape(self.theta[(self.dims[0]*self.dims[1]):self.theta.get_value().shape[0]], (self.dims[0],1))

    # the feed-forward function is not fully written 
    def feed_forward(self):
        f = t.dot(self.w, self.x.T) + self.b
        return f

    def get_cost_grads(self):
        cost = t.sum(t.abs_(self.feed_forward()))
        gradw = t.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.w).flatten()
        gradb = t.grad(cost=cost, wrt=self.b).flatten() 

        return cost, gradw, gradb


def training_functions(data, model, dims):
    cost, grad = model.get_cost_grads()
    fn = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=[cost, grad],
                         givens={model.x: data}, allow_input_downcast=True)

    def train_fn(theta_value):
        # reshape the theta value for Theano and convert to float32
        model.w = t.reshape(theta_value[0:(dims[0]*dims[1])], dims)
        model.b = t.reshape(theta_value[(dims[0]*dims[1]):theta_value.shape[0]], (dims[0],1))

        c, gw, gb = fn()
        # convert values to float64 for SciPy
        c = np.asarray(c, dtype=np.float64)
        gw = np.asarray(gw, dtype=np.float64)
        gb = np.asarray(gb, dtype=np.float64)
        grad = np.append(gw, gb)

        return c, grad

    return train_fn  


theta = theano.shared(np.random.randn((input_dim*hdim) + hdim), name='theta')

np.random.seed(0)
theta.set_value(np.random.randn((input_dim*hdim) + hdim).astype('float32'))

model = SparseFilter(theta, dims, x)
train_fn = training_functions(data, model, dims)

from scipy.optimize import minimize

weights = minimize(train_fn, model.theta.eval(),
                   method='L-BFGS-B', jac=True,
                   options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True})
```

There is no iteration and the oparation stops.
There is a message in the output
message: 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know why without any explanation someone just down voted this question.